# MediaElement Audio IE8 player.play() event "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a page using the MediaElement plugin. Everything works fine on chrome, however when in IE8, there seems to an issue with the method player.play() on the audio elements.

Taking the demo "mediaelementplayer-audio.html" in the download from version 2.3.0. If you then add the code "$('audio')[0].player.play();" after the code in the final script tag you will be able to see the problem in IE8 when you open the demo.

It seems to be as though the silverlight plugin isn't having an event fire from the javascript (is this right though as the documentation says it should be a flash plugin for mp3?). Or is there something I need to do in order for this to work?

Comment: I am in the same boat as well. Would love to see if we or somebody else can possibly suggest a possible solution to this issue with ME.js.

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 probably doesn't support all of HTML 5's JavaScript capabilities. The audio tag may show up, but that doesn't mean that javascript api's will work.